# Using Boost Python for C++ class which takes user input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, gcc, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ class which takes user input in the constructor and then writes that (and other stuff) onto a file. It works perfectly fine on C++ (both on MSVC and GCC) and now I would like to use this class in my Python projects. My files are:

**foo.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(const std::string file_name, const std::string other_input);
    virtual ~Foo();
    void Write(const std::string random_text);

private:
    std::ofstream output_file;
    char buffer[200];
    std::string random_string;
};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

// Constructor
Foo::Foo(const std::string file_name, const std::string other_input)
{
    std::ifstream file_exists(file_name)
    if(file_exists.good())
        output_file.open(file_name, std::ios_base::app);
    else
        output_file.open(file_name);

    random_string = other_input;
}

// Destructor
Foo::~Foo()
{
    output_file.close();
}

// Write to a file
void Foo::Write(const std::string random_text)
{
    sprintf( buffer, "%s", random_string );

    output_file << buffer << ";\n";
}

// Boost.Python wrapper
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo", boost::python::init<>())
        .def("Write", &Foo::Write)
        ;
}
```

When I try to compile this on Visual Studio or GCC, I am getting the following error:

```
'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

I am totally confused regarding why this is the case. I have tried another variant of the wrapper, namely:

```
// Boost.Python wrapper
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    boost::python::class_<Foo, boost::noncopyable>("Foo", boost::python::init<>())
        .def("Write", &Foo::Write)
        ;
}
```

And here I get the error:

```
'Foo' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

Any ideas to get this to heel would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One apparent mistake in your code is that `Foo`'s constructor takes two parameters that you have not included in the wrapper:

```
// Boost.Python wrapper
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
    boost::python::class_<Foo, boost::noncopyable>("Foo",
       boost::python::init<const std::string, const std::string>())
     .def("Write", &Foo::Write)
     ;
}
```

This explains the second error and this version (with `noncopyable`) should now compile fine.

Comment: This worked perfectly! However, now I am having weird errors while trying to build the python wrapping library. I have asked a different but related question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152546/linkage-errors-while-building-wrapping-class-using-boost-python). It would be awesome if you could take a look. Thanks!